# Did I just downvote this answer twice?

Tags: support

I absolutely loathe the fact that I have to link to [this garbage answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18939473/158779) to explain what I did because it is spam.

What I did in this order:

- Flagged the answer as spam
- Downvoted the answer
- Upvoted the answer (I know..I know..it was accident I swear)
- Downvoted the answer again to correct the mistake

When I did this the score changed like this:

- 0
- -1
- 0
- -2

So seeing the score go from 0 to -2 was a little odd so I started upvoting and downvoting again to see what happens. Maybe someone else downvoted it too so I wanted to see if that was the case. When I did this the score always switched between 0 and -2. I opened up a new browser and went back to the answer and tried again. It was still switching between 0 and -2.

So is this a bug or does my vote carry more weight because I flagged it or what? My hunch is that someone else probably downvoted at nearly the same time and perhaps that is what got things messed up, but obviously I do not know for sure.

**Update:**

Part of the confusion stems from flagging as spam has an implicit -1 vote (thanks animuson), but it does not get immediately reflected in the score; at least it did not for me. So when I downvoted the score went to -1 on my screen even though in reality it was actually -2. Then when I upvoted it went from -2 to 0 (like you would expect) except that I saw it transition from -1 to 0 and that's what got me twisted up into thinking pressing the up button retracts the down vote when in reality it switches to an upvote for a +2 gain. So if there is a bug it is that flagging as spam does not show up in the score immediately.

Comment: A spam flag has an implicit -1, and you can downvote the post on top of that, so yes, you can "downvote a post twice."

Comment: @icktoofay: Ah, yeah, you are absolutely right. I was thinking clicking the up button while the down button is orange retracts the vote, but it actually switches it to an upvote.

Comment: @animuson: Ah..I see. And then of course, like my previous comment pointed out, pressing the up button does not retract, but instead switches to an upvote. That is why it bounces between 0 and -2. So clearly this question can be disregarded. I think part of the confusion for me was that flagging as spam does not immediately show in the score. Again, not a big deal.

Comment: We might need a community manager or developer to check the database for a true answer.

Comment: @Undo Check for what?

Comment: @animuson Before this was attributed to a spam flag, I figured we would need someone to check the flags DB.